# Solr results differ when Webapp runs on different Server. Encoding issue?

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, encoding, utf-8, solr

i have the following situation:

I just moved a webapp i developed onto our production server and it seems, when i perform a search, the searchresults differ from what i get on my developmentserver, although i send the exact same requests to the exact same SOLR server. I don't know how to describe this, i just noticed, that on the resulttext, special characters are not being correctly displayed. I have occurences of German umlauts etc. everywhere in my pagetext, and everything works fine, except for the ones i read get out of the JSON object returned by SOLR. On my development server, these work fine too, so the issue clearly seems to be one of the production server.

As i don't know where to start looking, i have not included any code/config files, i will however happpily provide everything that can be helpful.

Thanks in advance for ANY hints you may come up with. Cheers!

Details:

- Tomcat 7 in both environments
- JSF 2.0/Spring

Comment: If you suspect this is an encoding issue, would you care to share the encodings that you have configured in various places? Maybe some fiddler/LiveHTTPHeaders/Firebug sampling, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml` files for both servers and check whether they differ in this line:

```
<Connector port="8080" ... URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```